# Uniqueness of Stabilized Planes in $SO(n)$ ($n$ odd)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k>0$ be even.  Denote elements of $SO(2)$ by $R_\theta$.  We know that every element, $A$, of $SO(n)$ can be conjugated into the form $\mathrm{diag}(1, R_{\theta_1}, \dots, R_{\theta_k})$.  Denote by $H_i$ ($i = 1, \dots, k$) the corresponding stabilized planes.  My question is this:

Assuming that none of the $\theta_i$ is zero, is $\left\{ H_i \right\}$ the only collection of planes that are stabilized by $A$?

This question can of course be phrased for $n$ being even as well, but I am currently working in my research with the Lie group $G_2 \subset SO(7)$, so I wanted ask the question within that context.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: consider the case when the $\theta_i$ are all equal and think of $\mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$ as $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}^k$. On the subspace $0 \times \mathbb{C}^k$, $A$ acts by multiplication by $e^{2\pi i \theta_1}$ on $\mathbb{C}^k$. So any subspace of the form $0 \times H$ where $H$ is a 1-dimensonal subspace of $\mathbb{C}^k$ is mapped to itself by $A$.

Comment: Thank you, Rob! Interestingly, it turns out the subgroup of $SO(7)$ I'm looking at has $\theta_3 = -(\theta_1+\theta_2)$, so that, since $\theta_i \neq 0$, we fall out of your hypotheses. Does the answer change then?

Comment: I don't think so: does the condition on your subgroup eliminate the possibility that $\theta_1 = \theta_2$, say?

Comment: No, that's allowed. My point was that we cannot have $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = -(\theta_1 + \theta_2)$ without $A = I$ (which I am excluding). But I see what you're saying: re-adjusting your proof, if $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \theta$, then $A$ acts as $\exp(i\theta)$ on $0 \times \mathbb{C}^2$. I have additional structure that I'm hiding right now that might let me deal with this case. It would be great if we could show the result true for the $\theta_i$ distinct.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, I've reduced to the case that $\theta \neq 0$, $\theta_1 = \theta$, $\theta_2 = -\theta$, so that $\theta_3 = 0$. So let's examine that case! :D

Comment: (noting possible complication if $\theta = \pi$)

Comment: (for which we've seen the stabilized plains are not unique)

Comment: Hey Rob, I posted this question separately, here, in case you want to post a solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488902/what-1d-mathbbc-subspaces-are-stabilized-by-elements-of-a-specific-2-torus